# how to insert UIImage into UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uitextview

im working on a editable notebook type project. it consists some text and images at any time.
in `UITextView` if we add images as subview the frames  are  fixed. but i have `editable` option. so i must save image as `NSString` format in `UITextView`, but it should look  image type in uipart. so please suggest me how can i handle this requierment.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @maddy did you solve your problem.I am also having the same problem.Please suggest me how you solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved as follows. Taken Scrollview, in that managing size of the textview & inserting image with Specified size. Like textview,image,tetxview, image and goes on...

Thanks for all your support to solve the issue.

Comment: hi madhu , can you please explain or give me some hint to adjust the frame of all subviews of scrollview,,

Answer (score 4):

I think you're asking for something that's not possible.

If you need to truly interleave text and graphics, UIWebView is about your only answer. But it's not editable.

Comment: This is right.  Text views can only show text in a single style.

Comment: thanks for reply.
yes i know its not possible. but my requirement is like above. so any suggestions to do images and text views at same place and which can be editable

Comment: Well, UIWebView can be made editable by loading an HTML file. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's too late.
As per my understanding, you can use `UIWebView` to insert text and images both.
 Create an HTML file and put it in app bundle. Set the attribute of `div or paragraph(in HTML)` as `contentEditable = "true"`.  And load that file:-

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSURL *indexFileURL = [bundle URLForResource:@"Index" withExtension:@"html"]; // HTML file name is "Index"
[YourWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:indexFileURL]];
```

This way, your `UIWebView` becomes editable and you can insert text and image both. 
 
**Edit:-** Please have a look at this link:- [Adding Images to UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263808/how-to-add-image-with-in-uitextview-just-like-in-stackoverflow-questin-box/13263870#13263870)

Comment: It should editable also, So it is not possible with UIWebview, anyway resolved the issue in below mentioned formate. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Yes, it is editable and is possible with UIWebView. You would have to use JavaScript. I did the same in one of my app.

Comment: Well, Okay but it was solved long back ago, at that time i have tried with same, no luck on that day.

Comment: Yes, agreed with you. My answer is too late. Good luck. :)

Comment: Thanks, wish you the same and Happy New Year :)

Comment: Thank you Sir. Same to you. :)

Comment: Hey buddy, I am male, not mam :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44691/discussion-between-piyush-dubey-and-madhu)