# How to include images/texts in UITextView in correct order

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am planning to develop a messenger app like Facebook Messenger/iMessage.But I don't know how to include images/texts in UITextView as inputs in the order.can any one suggest me a solution or a sample code? I am new in iPhone development.

Comment: you can insert text , it's default. but for Images you can only use unicode characters like emoji. User should enable emoji keyboard in order to use it.

Comment: i want to add images from the gallery/camera along with the text like in iMessage.But i am stuck with including it in textview

Comment: This might be the answer you are looking for [http://stackoverflow.com/a/10181449/971182][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10181449/971182

Comment: @AlexMarkman: Thanks.This what I am exactly looking for.But I dont know how to start with it :(

Comment: atleast you could have voted :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use UiTableView or ScrollView