# How to use custom emoticons in UITextview/UILabel?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios6

I am developing a messenger cross platform application.I would like to use my sets of custom images as emoticons.while searching for a solution i could find using existing emojis.First I am planing to develop in IOS.Any valuable suggestions/sample code will be appreciable

Answer (score 2):

Long story short, you hardly succeed with UITextView / UILabel.

Alternatives are:

- UIWebView
- Core Text facilities
- Overlaing emoticons upon UITextView

Quote from one good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10181449/612705):

> You would be better off using a UIScrollView and managing UITextViews and UIImageViews in it. UITextView doesn't support adding image inline with text. In fact, it doesn't really support anything other than multiline text.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Any links/sample code you can provide will be appreciable

Comment: I am following the same logic.but I got stuck in including images in between the texts

Comment: Inserting images between the texts can be done easily with Core Text, and also via UIWebView (html, you know <img src="...">) and so on. Personally I think overlaying kind of dirty trick, and I do not recommend it.