# Adding Images to UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiimageview, uitextview

In my app I have a `UITextView` and a button just below the text view to insert a photo into the `UITextView` while editing.

My requirement is that the user user is able to edit the text within, and insert images when needed.

Similar to StackOverflow's app's own `UITextView`:

[image]

Answer (score 18):

You can add the image view as a subView of `UITextView`.

Create an imageView with image:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:yourImage];
[imageView setFrame:yourFrame];
[yourTextView addSubview:imageView];
```

Edit:

For avoiding the overlapping use (Thanks @chris):

```
CGRect aRect = CGRectMake(156, 8, 16, 16);
[imageView setFrame:aRect];
UIBezierPath *exclusionPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(imageView.frame), CGRectGetMinY(imageView.frame), CGRectGetWidth(yourTextView.frame), CGRectGetHeight(imageView.frame))];
yourTextView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = @[exclusionPath];
[yourTextView addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: But how do you prevent the imageview from covering the text in the textview?  How do you get the text to flow around the imageview?

Comment: CGRect aRect = CGRectMake(156, 8, 16, 16);
    [attachmentView setFrame:aRect];
    UIBezierPath *exclusionPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(attachmentView.frame),
                                                                              CGRectGetMinY(attachmentView.frame), CGRectGetWidth(internalTextView.frame),
                                                                              CGRectGetHeight(attachmentView.frame))];
    
    internalTextView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = @[exclusionPath];
    [internalTextView addSubview:attachmentView];

Answer (score 10):

If you add it only as a subview, some text can be "behind" the image.
So add the code which will "tell" the text, that area of the image is inaccessible:

```
UIBezierPath *exclusionPath = [UIBezierPath    bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(imageView.frame),    
CGRectGetMinY(imageView.frame), CGRectGetWidth(imageView.frame), 
CGRectGetHeight(imageView.frame))];

textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = @[exclusionPath];
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out, [ios-5-rich-text-editing-series](http://ios-blog.co.uk/featured-posts/ios-5-rich-text-editing-series/) . In iOS 5 you can insert images and use HTML texts. You might have to use `UIWebview` and webkit.

You can also check with [EGOTextView](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTextView) which has a lot of rich text editing features.

Comment: @user1645721, If you want the user to start entering text after the image, you might have to use the above suggestions in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

just add as a subview of TextView like bellow..

```
    [yourTextView addSubview:yourImageView];
```

Answer (score 0):

Create subclass of UITextView and override this method

```
- (void)paste:(id)sender 
{
    NSData *data = [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] dataForPasteboardType:@"public.png"];

    if (data) 
    {

        NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[self attributedText] mutableCopy];

        NSTextAttachment *textAttachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];

        textAttachment.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data scale:5];

        NSAttributedString *attrStringWithImage = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:textAttachment];

        [attributedString replaceCharactersInRange:self.selectedRange withAttributedString:attrStringWithImage];

        self.attributedText = attributedString;

    }
    else
    {

        UIPasteboard *pasteBoard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];

        NSAttributedString *text = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:pasteBoard.string];

        NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [self.attributedText mutableCopy];

        [attributedString replaceCharactersInRange:self.selectedRange withAttributedString:text];

        self.attributedText = attributedString;

    }
}
```