# How to move/jump the cursor next line to the image view after inserting image with in the text view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiimageview, uitextview

I have inserted an image from the library in the text view using the image picker,

In pickeDelegate **`didFinishPickingImage`** method

```
imgview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

            NSString *messageText = [[NSString alloc]init];
            messageText = messageView.text;
            CGSize s = [messageText sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15] //define your textview font size
                               constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width - 40, MAXFLOAT)  //                                      lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];   
            CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, s.height+10, 50, 50);//use YourImageView. height and width 
            imgview.frame=frame;

            //[imgview setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30,30) ];
            [messageView addSubview:imgview];
```

And implemented logic to add image at the end of the last text using followin delegate method logic

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text;
{
      if ( [text isEqualToString:@"\n"] ) {

      }
      else
      {
            NSString *yourstring = [[NSString alloc]init];
            yourstring = textView.text;
            CGSize s = [yourstring sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15] //define your textview font size
                              constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width - 40, MAXFLOAT)  // - 40 For cell padding
                                  lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];   
            CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, s.height+10, 50, 50);//use YourImageView. height and width 
            imgview.frame=frame;
      }
      return YES;
}
```

but every time the *cursor starts just before* the image view,

But **`i need to jump/ move the cursor after the image when ever i added the image, jus like as folows,`**

My requrement is user can type text in text view and he can add an image with in the text view **then from the next line after image he can able to enter text again,**

just like we **attach images in this stack over flow box like this**

[image]

After insert image he could able to enter text again,

how to do this any help.. thanks in advance

my previous question: [Adding Images to UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263808/how-to-add-image-with-in-uitextview-just-like-in-stackoverflow-questin-box)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to your textfield respond after inserting image then-

```
    [YOURTEXTFIELD becomeFirstResponder];
```