# UITextField custom emoticons ( icons )

Tags: ios, unicode, uitextfield, emoticons

I have a little problem: I need to use custom emoticons in uitextfield, as I know - iOS emotions are unicode characters. To write system emoticon I just need to print something like \ue413 and it will become into the image. How I can do this with custom icons?

Comment: no, I want to use my custom images for emoticons, not built-in ones

Comment: I tried it quickly, too many issues arising with a custom image. But, would you like to use this approach - http://imgur.com/vCd3hmO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to insert an image into the UITextField, which reduces this question to be the same as: [Adding Images to UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263808/adding-images-to-uitextview)